# how to resolve this itext v5 pdf format error?

Tags: java, spring, itext, itext7

*Using itext and xmlworker version 5.5.13.2*

I have a need to convert static HTML with basic CSS into a pdf. But the resulting PDF has not right format/ spacing/ position. Can someone help me out by pointing the mistake i have done or the something i have missed in the code part.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
​
<head>

</head>
​
<body>
  <div style="margin:5px; width:100%">
    <div style="border:1px solid black;padding: 25px;">
      <div class="row1">
        <div class="floatR" style="min-width: 33%;width: 33%;min-height: 1px; float: right;">
          <h3>
            Tax Invoice/Bill Of Supply/ Cash Memo
          </h3>
          (Original for Recipient)
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row1 marginT50p">
        <div style="min-width: 33%;width: 33%;min-height: 1px;float: left;">
          <h4>
            Sold By:
            ArtisanIndia Shoppping Private Limited,
          </h4>
          Shop On Plot No. 7 and 8, 41 and 42, Vijay Nagar,
          Patrakar Colony Road, Mansarovar,
          Jaipur - 302020, Rajasthan
          State/UT Code: 08
          Country: India
        </div>
        <div style="min-width: 33%;width: 33%;min-height: 1px;float: left;"></div>
        <div style="min-width: 33%;width: 33%;min-height: 1px ;float: left;">
          <h4>
            Sold By:
            ArtisanIndia Shoppping Private Limited,
          </h4>
          Shop On Plot No. 7 and 8, 41 and 42, Vijay Nagar,
          Patrakar Colony Road, Mansarovar,
          Jaipur - 302020, Rajasthan
          State/UT Code: 08
          Country: India
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row1 marginT25">
        <div style="min-width: 33%;width: 33%;min-height: 1px;float: left;">
          <label class="textUnderline">Comapny GSTIN:</label>JKDHFBGKJDJHJ
          <br />
          <label class="textUnderline">Comapny PAN:</label>SDJKHFGB
        </div>
        <div style="min-width: 33%;width: 33%;min-height: 1px;float: left;"></div>
        <div style="min-width: 33%;width: 33%;min-height: 1px;float: left;">
          <label class="textUnderline">Biller GSTIN:</label>JKDHFBGKJDJHJ
          <br />
          <label class="textUnderline">Biller PAN:</label>SDJKHFGB
        </div>
      </div>
​
      <div class="row1 marginT25">
        <div style="min-width: 33%;width: 33%;min-height: 1px;float: left;">
          <label class="textBold">Order ID:</label>235235
          <br />
          <label class="textBold">Order Date:</label>12/12/1912
        </div>
        <div style="min-width: 33%;width: 33%;min-height: 1px;float: left;"></div>
        <div style="min-width: 33%;width: 33%;min-height: 1px;float: left;">
          <label class="textBold">Shipping Address:</label>
          <br />
          <label class="textBold"> </label>
          <br />
          Shop On Plot No. 7 and 8, 41 and 42, Vijay Nagar,
          Patrakar Colony Road, Mansarovar,
          Jaipur - 302020, Rajasthan
          State/UT Code: 08
          Country: India
        </div>
      </div>
​
      <div class="row1 marginT25">
        <div style="min-width: 33%;width: 33%;min-height: 1px;float: left;">
​
          <label class="textBold">Invoice Date:</label>12/12/1912
          <br />
          <label class="textBold">Order ID:</label>AI/2012/907656767
​
        </div>
        <div style="min-width: 33%;width: 33%;min-height: 1px;float: left;"></div>
        <div style="min-width: 33%;width: 33%;min-height: 1px;float: left;">
          <label class="textBold">Place Of Supply:</label> Maharastra
          <br />
          <label class="textBold">Place Of Delivery:</label>Maharastra
​
        </div>
      </div>
​
      <div class="row1 marginT25">
        <table style="width:100%">
          <tr>
            <th>Sr. No.</th>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>HSN</th>
            <th>GST %</th>
            <th>QTY</th>
            <th>Gross Amount</th>
            <th>Discount</th>
            <th>Taxable value</th>
            <th>CGST</th>
            <th>SGST</th>
            <th>IGST</th>
            <th>Total</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Product Description</td>
            <td>Item Description</td>
            <td>123456</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Product Description</td>
            <td>Item Description</td>
            <td>123456</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>Product Description</td>
            <td>Item Description</td>
            <td>123456</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
​
          <tr>
            <td colspan="5">Total</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
​
      </div>
      <div class="row1">
        <div style="min-width: 25%; width: 25%; min-height: 1px;float: left;">
          <label class="textUnderline textBold">
            Seller Registered Address:
            ArtisanIndia Shoppping Private Limited,
          </label>
          Shop On Plot No. 7 and 8, 41 and 42, Vijay Nagar,
          Patrakar Colony Road, Mansarovar,
          Jaipur - 302020, Rajasthan
          State/UT Code: 08
          Country: India
        </div>
      </div>
​
      <div class="row1 marginT50p">
        <div style="min-width: 25%; width: 25%; min-height: 1px;float: left;">
          E. & O. E.
​
        </div>
        <div class=" floatR" style="min-width: 25%; width: 25%; min-height: 1px; float: right;">
          <div class="signbox">
            Sign/Stamp
          </div>
          <span> Ordered Through
          </span>
          <span class="textUnderline">
​
            ArtisanIndia Shoppping Pvt Limited
​
            <br />
            Authorized Signature
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
​
</body>
​
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
    * {
      font-family: sans-serif;
      font-size:8px
    }

    .width33 {
      min-width: 33%;
      width: 33%;
      min-height: 1px;
      border:1px solid red
    }

    .width25 {
      min-width: 25%;
      width: 25%;
      min-height: 1px;
      border: 1px solid green;

    }

    .row1:after {
      content: "";
      display: table;
      clear: both;
    }

    .floatL {
      float: left;
    }

    .floatR {
      float: right;
    }

    .marginT25 {
      margin-top: 25px;
    }

    .marginT50p {
      margin-top: 50px
    }

    .textUnderline {
      text-decoration: underline;
    }

    .textBold {
      font-weight: bold;
    }

    table,
    th,
    td {
      border: 1px solid black;
      border-collapse: collapse;
font-size: 10px;
    }

    th,
    td {
      height: 40px;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .signbox {
      vertical-align: middle;
      text-align: center;
      height: 50px;
      border: 1px solid black;
      /* margin: auto; */
    }
```

**Java**

```
        UploadUtil s3Upload = new UploadUtil();
        PdfWriter pdfWriter = null;
        
        ByteArrayOutputStream gg = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try{
            Document document = new Document();       

            PdfWriter.getInstance(document, gg);
            document.open();
            XMLWorkerHelper xmlWorkerHelper = XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance();

            
            xmlWorkerHelper.parseXHtml(pdfWriter, document, new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\jj\\Desktop\\asdf\\tt.html"), new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\jj\\Desktop\\asdf\\ttt.css"));
            
            document.close();
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\jj\\Desktop\\asdf\\test.pdf");
            fos.write(gg.toByteArray());
            fos.close();
            
                        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("asdf");
        }
```

### **the resulting pdf generated looks something like this.**

[image]

### **instead of**

[image]

Can someone out here point out the reason why this is happening or what I have missed or done wrong?

Answer (score 1):

iText 5.5.13.2 is the old version of iText product and it's not supported anymore. Most likely there are some not supported functionality in the html or css. I can guess that float properties are not supported. Probably there are issues with percentage width. You can try to play around with your html and css files to try to make pdf look acceptable, but the easiest way is to use the newest version of iText product which is iText 7

Comment: needed a free alternative and hence i was using v5